# Why there are no popular manga series based on light novels?

Tags: anime-production, manga-production, light-novel-production

Correct me if I'm wrong, but, why are there no popular manga series based on light novels? I know that there are many anime based on light novels that are popular such as Sword Art Online, Oreimo, Monogatari Series, Melancholy of Haruhi Suzumiya, or Kara no Kyoukai. But for some reason, there are no popular manga adaptations from light novels, whether the light novel has been adapted into an anime - like SAO manga, or Oreimo manga (I think these two manga are not as popular as the anime or any other manga) - or not.

Comment: How are you defining popular?

Comment: @kuwaly maybe like widely known and many people like it so the manga never on hiatus?

Comment: @student080705639 Popularity of a work does not have anything to do with hiatus. (Consider *Hunter x Hunter*.)

Comment: IMO, its because LN and Anime are "opposite" mediums. In LN you fully use your imagination to visualize things, and in anime you veg out and have the visuals delivered on silver platter. Manga is this in between thing that delivers visuals, but not as good as anime, and the consumer still has to read.

Comment: @kuwaly While popular might be subjective, I'm pretty sure the OP is referring to the manga receiving commercial success

Comment: Semi-counterexample: A Certain Scientific Railgun (popular manga) spun off from A Certain Magical Index (original light novel). They tell different stories, of course, but are very closely related, featuring many of the same characters, and even retelling the same events in some cases.

Comment: Man I sure botched my first answer. @senshin Most of the LN that have manga aren't translated, and only start to translate as they get an anime series.

Comment: Just speculating here, but maybe the publishers don't hype the manga versions as much because they're using the manga as a test to see if it's worth making an anime, and don't care as much if it succeeds.

Comment: I feel it should be noted that [the Monogatari Series now has a manga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogatari_(series)#Manga).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a decent amount of research, I have to retract my previous answer.

There are in fact a lot of series that started as Light Novels and achieved commercialized success. Some include Accel World, Zero no Tsukaima, Haruhi Suzumiya, and Shakugan no Shana.
Their order of progression was LN -> Manga -> Anime.

Then there are still LN today that have a manga, but no anime , such as Kagerou Project (although scheduled for Spring 2014).